# When using Options from Database with no Value or Label... how do I customise what is displayed to the user

Tags: react-select

When using Options from Database with no Value or Label... how do I customise what is displayed to the user.

I don't have Value or Label in my database, so it displays the correct list of information that I want to select from... but obviously it's blank because the database doesn't contain Value or Label items.

Comment: What is the structure of your data you want to display as options?